# MySql: 2000 records -or- a text field.. what's more efficient?

Tags: mysql

I need to save a pair of coordinates X, Y in millimeters... About 2000 pairs per session per user.

Assuming 5k users per year using our app... and 2 sessions per user.. that's 20 million pairs of coordinates X,Y.

I need to choose between 2 ways to store the pairs on MySQL:

1. One record per session with a text field contain a Json array of pairs of coordinates X,Y.
   With the estimate above, we would have 10k records
2. One record per each pair of coordinates X,Y 
   With the estimate above, we would have 20 million records

What will be more efficient for my app?

Comment: how about create prove of concept app and see which method is more   efficient?

Comment: Just did it and answered my own question. It was 2000 MS versus 10 milliseconds.. Solution #1 won

Comment: Right, because each record is associated with a record number making option 2 end up with 20 million record fields whereas option 1 only has 10 thousand records and presumably the string is not too long.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is what you need the database to do.  Storing the values as a string/array/binary large object (BLOB) effectively means that SQL does not know about them -- you cannot search through them easily, you cannot sort by them, and so on.

If you store them as separate rows in a table with multiple columns, with at least three columns, `sessionid`, `x`, `y`, then you can do more SQL-type things with them.  For instance, you could get all sessions where the `x` value is between 3.1415 and 3.1415926.

This may not be important for your application.  If so, just thinking about the data as a big BLOB might be sufficient, and storing the data in an appropriate text or BLOB field would be fine.

Comment: Absolutely. Sorry I forgot to mention I don't need to do much at the MySql level.. meaning.. no need to search for specific values. I only need to get ALL of the records for a session, with no specific search.

Comment: @user3158468 - if you just need to dump he values into mysql and fetch them all at once, I'd suggest to try out both and compare the footprints on the storage. The less footprint you have, the better and probably faster. Significantly faster? Maybe. All you need is to test.

Comment: @user3158468 . . . As my answer suggests, if you don't need to use the values, then a BLOB or text is fine for the values.